# How to draw in J2ME with float or double point?

Tags: java-me, canvas

I draw in J2ME with Canvas, but graphics support only integer. So how can I draw with float or double point ?

Answer (score 2):

convert your points to relative integer. or, if your double points is 0<= points<1, 
then, get the screen size say, width and height, then `x = xx * width` and `y = yy * height`